# ¿Cómo enviar parámetros a través de clases creadas mediante WSDL generadas con jax-ws?

Tags: java, spring, maven, wsdl

He generado las siguientes clases a partir de un `wsdl`, el problema es que no sé cuál es la manera correcta de invocar al servicio y que este me devuelva datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase **CiudadanoConsultar.java** contiene el siguiente código el cual invoco para llamar al servicio, a lo mucho he logrado que me aparezca un mensaje en el LOG confirmándome la creación del servicio, pero no parece estar reconociendo los parámetros que le estoy enviando.

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "CiudadanoConsultar", targetNamespace = "http://soa.osinergmin.org.pe/service/consultaidentificacion/ciudadano/consultar/1.0", 
              wsdlLocation = "http://xxxx/consultaidentificacion/ciudadano/consultar/1.0?WSDL")
public class CiudadanoConsultar extends Service{

private final static URL CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_WSDL_LOCATION;
private final static WebServiceException CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_EXCEPTION;
private final static QName CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_QNAME = new QName("http://soa.osinergmin.org.pe/service/consultaidentificacion/ciudadano/consultar/1.0", "CiudadanoConsultar");

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://xxxx/consultaidentificacion/ciudadano/consultar/1.0?WSDL");
    }catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_EXCEPTION = e;
}

public CiudadanoConsultar() {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_QNAME);
}

public CiudadanoConsultar(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_QNAME, features);
}

public CiudadanoConsultar(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_QNAME);
}

public CiudadanoConsultar(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_QNAME, features);
}

public CiudadanoConsultar(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public CiudadanoConsultar(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns CiudadanoConsultarPT
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "CiudadanoConsultarPort")
public CiudadanoConsultarPT getCiudadanoConsultarPort() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://soa.osinergmin.org.pe/service/consultaidentificacion/ciudadano/consultar/1.0", "CiudadanoConsultarPort"), CiudadanoConsultarPT.class);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param features
 *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
 * @return
 *     returns CiudadanoConsultarPT
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "CiudadanoConsultarPort")
public CiudadanoConsultarPT getCiudadanoConsultarPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://soa.osinergmin.org.pe/service/consultaidentificacion/ciudadano/consultar/1.0", "CiudadanoConsultarPort"), CiudadanoConsultarPT.class, features);
}

private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
    if (CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_EXCEPTION!= null) {
        throw CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_EXCEPTION;
    }
    return CIUDADANOCONSULTAR_WSDL_LOCATION;
}

}
```

Si alguien podría guiarme de qué manera puedo hacer una consulta utilizando las clases creadas le agradecería bastante, ya llevo un par de días en esto.

Answer (score 0):

`CiudadanoConsultar` no es la clase que tienes que usar. Esta clase solo te devuelve un *stub*, una clase local con los métodos del WS y que se encarga de hacer la llamada.

Lo que tienes que hacer es instanciar `CiudadanoConsultar` e invocar `getCiudadanoConsultarPort()`. Esto te devolverá una instancia de `CiudadanoConsultarPT`, que es donde estarán definidos los métodos del WS.

Comment: Hola amigo si lo he intentado de esa manera pero solo me devuelve un mensaje que me confirma que se esta creando el servicio...

Comment: Con el nuevo código, te debería salir algo o dar un error (el mensaje que te sale lo genera automáticamente el código del WS). Es posible que el servidor no esté respondiendo, y estés parando el servicio antes de que de un timeout (que te lanzaría una excepción). Prueba de llamar al servidor haciendo peticiones con herramientas como soapui.

Comment: ya lo he probado de esa manera, y si me devuelve los datos de la persona con ese dni

Answer (score 0):

Hola SJuan76 gracias por tu comentario, te comento que si he intentado realizar la consulta de la manera que tu dices:

```
CiudadanoConsultarReqParamTYPE request = new CiudadanoConsultarReqParamTYPE();
CiudadanoConsultarRespParamTYPE response = new CiudadanoConsultarRespParamTYPE();
CiudadanoConsultar consultar = new CiudadanoConsultar();
CiudadanoConsultarPT interfaz = consultar.getCiudadanoConsultarPort();

request.setNumDni("20904254");
request.setFlagDatos("1");

response = interfaz.ciudadanoConsultar(request);

LOG.info(response.getDeResultado());
```

y solo he logrado que el LOG me devuelva lo siguiente:

```
INFO org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean - Creating Service {http://soa.osinergmin.org.pe/service/consultaidentificacion/ciudadano/consultar/1.0}CiudadanoConsultar from WSDL: http://11.160.124.169:9505/consultaidentificacion/ciudadano/consultar/1.0?WSDL
```

Talves no estoy cargando el servicio con alguna cabecera necesaria, es ahi mi duda...

Comment: Evita poner "respuestas" que no lo sean. Tienes el botón "editar" para modificar y añadir información a tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, soy nuevo en esto, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que lo que hagas sea utilizar una clase manager para hacer la invocación del servicio web.

```
CiudadanoConsultar consultar = new CiudadanoConsultar();
CiudadanoConsultarPT interfaz = consultar.getCiudadanoConsultarPort();
```

Aunque yo te recomiendo que al hacer la creacion del cliente uses la URL real del web service, lo anterior con el objetivo que sea parametrizable.

```
CiudadanoConsultar consultar = new CiudadanoConsultar(URL_WSDL);
CiudadanoConsultarPT interfaz = consultar.getCiudadanoConsultarPort();
```

*NOTA: esta parte e simportante por que mucas veces los nombres de dominio que vienen en los WSDL no son reconocibles desde las maquins de desarrollo, entonces tendrías que usar la IP:PUERTO o configurar tu archivo de hosts para solucionar este problema,

Una vez tengas esto debes tener claro cual es el metodo que vas a invocar a traves del Port, en tu caso creo es `ciudadanoConsultar`  con esto ya te debería funcionar sin ningun problema.

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu comentario, lo he intentado de la manera que dices pero el resultado es el mismo, por otro lado como podría configurar el archivo de hosts, podrías ser más específico con eso porfavor? Lo que pasa es que no domino mucho este entorno...